constexpr sorted array of struct key value how to search it efficiently?
I have a long array of key+value data that I would like to initialize into my source code with constexpr initializer. I can sort the array myself in the source code, so it could be efficiently searched with a binary search algorithm. The structure has a key part and one (or more) value parts.
Here is a simple example of what I mean:
struct MyArrayElement { const char* key, int value };
constexpr MyArrayElement MyArray[] = {
 { "abc", 923 },
 { "def", 456 },
 /* ... */
 { "xyz", 178 },
};

I can use STL algorithm find_if to search for the key:
std::string key_to_find{ "xyz" };
auto const elem = find_if(std::begin(MyArray), std::end(MyArray),
  [&key_to_find](auto const& elem){ return key_to_find == elem.key; });

As the find_if algorithm cannot know that I have sorted the keys, it will not be able to take advantage of that knowledge to efficiently search the array.
I had a look at std::binary_search, but this seems to want to equate the whole Element (i.e. both key and value) and I only want to specify a key in the search predicate.
I have looked over the various STL algorithm, but nothing stood out that does what I want. I could always very easily write my own binary search template function, but I was hoping to use an off the shelf standard algorithm.
So these are my potential options in order of most to least preferred:

Try to find a different standard algorithm that does binary search on just the key field of the structure.
Try to find a different container that can be constructed constexpr and is better designed for efficient search.
Write my own binary search template function that will search only on the key field.
Split the key and value structures into 2 separate arrays, but this will no doubt make maintaining the code much more prone to error, because they will be on different lines of the source code.

I'm open to other ideas on how to solve this problem.

You can give binary_search a predicate like find_if so you only check the key member of the object.

Thanks for taking the time to help me @NathanOliver.  I agree the predicate can just look at the key part of the Element, but I'm failing to see how the "value" argument in binary_search can be just the key part of the Element and not a whole Element.  Did I miss something obvious?

Adding a link to a similar question I found afterwards, just for reference - How to use std::lower_bound when the key is part of the data and i want to search for the key?

Assuming that you want to look up a key and use the corresponding value, binary_search isn't appropriate, because it just gives you a bool (whether it's present or not.)
std::ranges::lower_bound will give you an iterator that you can use to fetch the value. However, it always gives you the first element greater than or equal to your search key, so it will succeed even if your search key is not in the list (unless it's after the last key in the list). So you might want to check if the returned iterator's key is the one you were looking for.
You can use the "projection" argument (the fourth argument to std::ranges::lower_bound) to tell it to compare based on the key value. This can either be a lambda or other callable taking an element and returning the key, or it can simply be a pointer-to-member, like &MyArrayElement::key.
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

struct MyArrayElement { const char* key; int value; };

constexpr MyArrayElement MyArray[] = {
 { "abc", 923 },
 { "def", 456 },
 { "xyz", 178 },
};

int main() {
    auto compare = [](std::string_view a, std::string_view b){ return a < b; };
    std::cout << std::ranges::lower_bound(MyArray, "def", compare, &MyArrayElement::key)->value << '\n';

    return 0;
}


This is much nicer than my answer! +1

@nickmatteo, this looks like what I was after. I will do some testing. I especially like the string_view so I can search with either string or literal.

@joe90_supermarionation Regarding your now removed comment:  lower_bound will return an iterator to the first element not less than the value searched for so you need to check if the returned iterator points at an element that has the key you searched for. Example

@TedLyngmo, thanks. I see now that NickMatteo also mentioned it too in his answer. This is quite important difference to find_if(), so thanks both of you for highlighting it.

You can use std::lower_bound:
// Compare function:
auto Comp = [](const MyArrayElement& lhs, const MyArrayElement& rhs) {
    return std::strcmp(lhs.key, rhs.key) < 0;
};

MyArrayElement searchkey{"key_to_search_for"};

auto it =
    std::lower_bound(std::begin(MyArray), std::end(MyArray), searchkey, Comp);

// check if the key was found and print the associated value:
if (it != std::end(MyArray) && std::strcmp(it->key, searchkey.key) == 0) {
    std::cout << it->value << '\n';
}

Demo
If you don't want to construct a whole new element to search for, you could make the comparator more advanced:
struct Comp {
    bool operator()(const char* lhs, const char* rhs) {
        return std::strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
    }
    bool operator()(const MyArrayElement& lhs, const char* rhs) {
        return std::strcmp(lhs.key, rhs) < 0;
    }
    bool operator()(const char* lhs, const MyArrayElement& rhs) {
        return std::strcmp(lhs, rhs.key) < 0;
    }
    bool operator()(const MyArrayElement& lhs, const MyArrayElement& rhs) {
        return std::strcmp(lhs.key, rhs.key) < 0;
    }
};

Then you could search using only a C string:
const char* searchkey = "def";

auto it = std::lower_bound(std::begin(MyArray), std::end(MyArray),
                            searchkey, Comp{});

if (it != std::end(MyArray) && std::strcmp(it->key, searchkey) == 0) {
    std::cout << it->value << '\n';
}

Demo

ok i see your answer constructs a whole Element as the search key, instead of just the search key itself. I was hoping to avoid constructing a whole Element, but maybe that isn't so bad in my specific case. Thanks very much for this suggestion.

@joe90_supermarionation I added an alternative that doesn't require creating a MyArrayElement to do the search, but really, take a look at Nicks answer. That's really nice if you can use C++20 or later.

Hi again @TedLyngmo, I'm reading again your answer to improve my understanding. In your answer you compare it != std::end(MyArray) but it isn't obvious to me in what circumstance that it could be equal to std::end(MyArray)?

@joe90_supermarionation If the last key is xyz but you search for zzz for example.

Thank You!  I was off on a tangent, thinking it might somehow be related to having an empty list for MyArray, but my compiler was refusing to compile that. With your example, it makes total sense now.

The answer from Nick Matteo is a great answer, but it requires C++20 or higher because it uses ranges. I'm aware some people are still stuck using older C++ standards for one reason or another (including myself depending on the project). So I've tried to find a solution for C++17 (or higher), using the ideas from Nick Matteo and Ted Lyngmo. Also another question I found very useful:
How to use std::lower_bound when the key is part of the data and i want to search for the key?
This other similar question has an answer from HolyBlackCat using std::partition_point, that I liked very much.
If you need something that works with a standard earlier than C++17, i.e. not using std::string_view, then take a look at Ted's answer.
In this answer, similar to Nick's answer, I recommend to modify the type for key to be a std::string_view (that is available from C++17), and this is very nice because it allows me to call my function with either a string or literal equally well.  Also it simplifies the comparison operations considerably, and avoids using the C function strcmp.
// Requires C++17 or higher
const MyArrayElement* find_element_in_myarray(std::string_view key_to_find)
{
  auto elem = std::partition_point(std::begin(MyArray), std::end(MyArray),
    [&key_to_find](const MyArrayElement &elem){return elem.key < key_to_find;});

  // check if we found the element or not
  bool found{true};
  if (elem==std::end(MyArray) || key_to_find != elem->key) {
    std::cout << "Not Found '" << key_to_find << "'\n";
    found = false;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Found '" << elem->key << "' = '" << elem->value << "'\n";
  }
  return found? elem : nullptr;
}

Note that it is necessary to check if the iterator is at the end of MyArray, and also check that the key is not equal to key_to_find. The reason is that partition_point (and lower_bound) will return an iterator that correspond to the point in the array where the element should have been if it were not missing.  In the case where we reach the end of the MyArray, we need to be extra careful we do not try to dereference that non-existing element, that is why we check for that case first.
